# plot GPS position over the road

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

How can I plot GPS trajectory over road and zoom on that road?

Can someone please take a point (40.74640013950355, -73.98755303328286, in Manhattan) and plot it over the corresponding road network [may be a grid 600ft by 600ft]. Please edit the code below to illustrate -

```
lat <- 40.74640013950355
long <- -73.98755303328286

tbl <- tibble(lat, long)

ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = lat,
           y = long)) +
  geom_point()
```

Once I know how to plot the road and I can overlay my trajectory data by modifying tbl above.

Thanks

Comment: (1) read in, likely with `read.csv`. (2) determine what a "road network" is, I'm not certain based on what you've provided here. (3) decide between base graphics (and then one of `plot`, `points`, and/or `lines`, though other options likely exist) or `ggplot2` (a whole different discussion).

Comment: Thank you very much @r2evans. Can you please take any one lat long (e.g. 40.74493704194405, -73.98979536004757, in Manhattan) and please show us how to plot this point over the corresponding road network [600ft by 600 ft]. I have been struggling to get it done.

Comment: (2) What is a "road network"? I am feeling rather dim, wondering if everybody else knows what this is, because while I work in gps data daily (not in a routing/directions way, though), I don't know that.

Comment: Please pardon me if I am not using the correct terminology here. I meant to say the road on which the point lies. (https://rdrr.io/cran/tigris/man/roads.html). I used the example from here but it shows all the roads. I don't know how can I zoom in, near a known lat-long point

Comment: Okay, I'm out ... coordinates and plotting are one thing, I don't know `ggmap` nor how to know what pixels on a PNG is a road or not.

Comment: you inverted lat and long in your ggplot asthetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no big difficulty to achieve such plot, starting from the example given in **tigris** library:

```
library(tigris)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
roads <- roads("Maine", "031")
gg <- ggplot() + geom_sf(data = roads, color="black", fill="white", size=0.25) + theme_map()
lat <- 43.5; long <- -70.6; bbox = 0.02 
bbox_gg = coord_sf(xlim=c(long-bbox/2, long+bbox/2), ylim=c(lat-bbox/2, lat+bbox/2))
gg + geom_point(data=data.frame(lat, long), aes(x=long, y=lat), size=4, color="red") + bbox_gg
```

What is done here is just adding a `geom_point()` aesthetic on top of the `geom_sf()` layer. We can use a kind of bounding box coordinate limit to adjust the zoom

[image]

**EDIT**

If you need some road names on your map, you can add this to the plot:
`geom_sf_label(data=subset(roads, roads$RTTYP!="M"), aes(label=FULLNAME))`
here I use subset to avoid plotting *all* little road names. Eventually, you might want to find a way to zoom/subset your data before plotting, because it's gonna be too long to do it like this.

Comment: Can you please tell me if we can add the name of main road or make this lo better, sorry I am asking for too much here

Comment: @SiD well, you could do it using `geom_sf_label()` method see edit